# MVC - should a Model return a List<string> instead of itself or should a new model be created

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC and part of the project is a product selector. The user answers some questions and then after answering these questions 3 suggested products are returned.

The model is:

```
public class TVDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TV> TVs { get; set; }

    }
```

The first question the user answers is how much space they have for the TV. Depending on the answer certain types of TVs are excluded as none of the TVs of that type can fit in the space they have. This then means that certain options are excluded from being asked on the second question which asks what type of TV they would like.

I want to make an AJAX call to the TV controller which then calls the TV model to find out from the database what TV types should be excluded from the type question. I am wondering whether I should have a method in the TV model to return to the controller what TV types should be excluded. Some thing like this:

```
        public List<string> GetAllowableTypes(int width, int height, int length)
        {
            //access database to get the TVs that can fit in the space

            //use LINQ to select the distinct TV Types

            //return a list of the types of TVs that will fit
        }
```

Or should I create a separate model that queries the TV table?

I will probably not be using DBContext in the model so that can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an additional model object with an additional table. And add the identifier from these new table to my tv-table.

Comment: All the information is in the TV table already. The attributes of width, height and length are in the table. I will do a query to the TV table to return all the TVs that can fit in the specified dimensions and then do a distinct on all the TV types to get my answer. Should I be using a different model to access the same table that the TV model accesses?

Comment: Are you talking about types or attributes?

Comment: A field in the database and data model called "type". When I say "I will do a query to the TV table to return all the TVs that can fit in the specified dimensions and then do a distinct on all the TV types to get my answer." TV types refers to all the different values that are contained in the TV table column called "type".